# Jenkins bitbucket integration

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, bitbucket

I am trying to integrate Bitbucket with Jenkins. I don't want to use web hooks, thus I am using the SCM polling option in Jenkins.

The GIT plugin needs a bitbucket URL and I have given my bitbucket master project URL. I am using SSH for the authentication.

My jenkins server has a slave machine, so I have created an SSH keypair for a enterprise service user in the slave machine. I have given the public key in the bitbucket accouunt settings of the user and given private key in the jenkins.

But I am getting the following error message when I enter the repository URL:

> Failed to connect to repositoriy : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot open session, connection is not authenticated.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is your private ssh key passphrase-protected?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add your error message as quote here.

Comment: No its not passphrase protected.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot open session, connection is not authenticated.

This is the error message when i select the credentials i have given . I have given public key in the bitbucket settings and private key in the credentials config dialogue of jenkins Git plugin . The slave machine has a enterprise user account "foo" and the same user has account in bitbucket . So i created ssh keypair of "foo" in the slave machine .

Comment: @VonC , Should the passphrase mandatory ?

Comment: @JavaProgrammer no, I would recommend testing it out without passphrase at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jenkins was using jGit as the git client , so it was looking for the private key in the server , not in the slave ,jGit works that way . The command line Git would look for the keys in the slave under /user/.ssh . Added the public key of the Jenkins master in the Bitbucket and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins needs defined credentials in order to be able to connect to an SSH git URL. You'll need to define a new set of credentials (of type SSH with a private key) and either paste the private key directly into Jenkins UI or point jenkins at the private key location on the Jenkins **master**.
Then - after defining the repo URL you'll need to choose the correct credentials from the drop-down list. This should solve your connection problem.

Comment: I did the same , but its showing authentication error. I defined the key already . I created ssh key pair in the slave machine , the same user has bit bucket account as well. I added the public key in the bitbucket .